# Launching an AWS EC2 with a specified private address and/or hostname?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

We do continuous integration from Jenkins, and have Jenkins deploy to an EC2 instance. This EC2 instance exports an NFS share of the deployed code to EC2 processing nodes. The processing nodes mount the NFS share.

Jenkins needs to be able to "find" this code-sharing EC2 instance and scp freshly-built code, and the processing nodes need to "find" this code-sharing EC2 instance and mount its NFS share.

These communications happen over private IP space, with our on-premise Jenkins communicating with our EC2 in a Direct Connect VPC subnet, not using public IP addresses.

***Is there a straightforward way to reliably "address" (by static private IP address, hostname, or some other method) this code-sharing EC2 that receives scp'd builds and exports them via NFS? We determine the subnet at launch, of course, but we don't know how to protect against changes of IP address if the instance is terminated and relaunched.***

We're also eagerly considering other methods for deployment, such as the new EFS or S3, but those will have to wait a little bit until we have the bandwidth for them.

Thanks!

-Greg

Comment: Have you looked at CodeDeploy? There's even a Jenkins plugin so you can push your code at the end of your build.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, that most definitely looks like the kind of option at would be best for us eventually, or even fairly soon! Hoping for a short-term workaround for the current inefficient setup, but we may need to bite the bullet and take the time to get it right sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a single instance at any given time that is this "code-sharing" instance you can assign an [Elastic IP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) to it when after you've launched it. This will give you a fixed public IP that you can target.
Elastic IPs are reserved and static until you release them. Keep in mind that they cost money when they are not reserved.

Further on you can use SecurityGroups to limit access to the instance.

Comment: We need to have this on our private Direct Connect VPN...not sure that Elastic IPs are meant for anything but public IPs...? Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Ok, I understand. ElasticIP are not addressable over VPN the way you want to. An alternative could be to assign a dns name in Route53 after the instance has launched that points to the private IP of the instance. That way you can always adress the dns instead of having to figure out the private IP.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, we created & saved a network interface, assigning one of our private IPs to it. When recycling the EC2, and making a new one in the same role, we just assign that saved interface (with its IP) to the new EC2. Seems to get the job done for us!